# Find all possible dominoes chains with recursion and backtracking

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

I'm working on a challange where I need to find all possibilities for linear chains of dominoes tiles. I understand the principle of recursion but not how to translate it to code. If someone could maybe explain the problem (solution) in simple steps, which I could then follow and try to code them.

> Example:
>
> Tiles : **[3/4] [5/6] [1/4] [1/6]**
>
> Possible chain : **[3/4]-[4/1]-[1/6]-[6/5]**

It's allowed to flip the tiles. (switching the numbers)

Comment: Is it all the possible chains or all the possible chains using all the dominoes?

Comment: Please have a go first then come back with a specific question relating to a problem with your implementation. At the moment you've just posted a requirements dump. If this is for your study, the main point of the exercise will be to interpret the requirements and design a solution using the required techniques yourself.

Comment: @spacedk ask yourself how you would do with a real set of dominoes, then try and convert that into logic. If you're using recursion try to identify what your base case(s) and recursive case(s) are.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: As iBug said, don't deface your posts. I've rolled back your destructive edit. Don't do that again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process is very simple: you start with a collection of dominoes D, and an empty chain C.

```
for each domino in the collection:
    see if it can be added to the chain (either the chain is empty, or the first 
    number is the same as the second number of the last domino in the chain.
    if it can, 
        append the domino to the chain,
        then print this new chain as it is a solution,
        then call recursively with D - {domino} and C + {domino}

    repeat with the flipped domino
```

Java code:

```
public class Domino {
    public final int a;
    public final int b;

    public Domino(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public Domino flipped() {
        return new Domino(b, a);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + a + "/" + b + "]";
    }
}
```

Algorithm:

```
private static void listChains(List<Domino> chain, List<Domino> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
        Domino dom = list.get(i);
        if (canAppend(dom, chain)) {
            chain.add(dom);
            System.out.println(chain);
            Domino saved = list.remove(i);
            listChains(chain, list);
            list.add(i, saved);
            chain.remove(chain.size()-1);
        }
        dom = dom.flipped();
        if (canAppend(dom, chain)) {
            chain.add(dom);
            System.out.println(chain);
            Domino saved = list.remove(i);
            listChains(chain, list);
            list.add(i, saved);
            chain.remove(chain.size()-1);
        }
    }
}

private static boolean canAppend(Domino dom, List<Domino> to) {
    return to.isEmpty() || to.get(to.size()-1).b == dom.a;
}
```

Your example:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    List<Domino> list = new ArrayList<>();
    // [3/4] [5/6] [1/4] [1/6]
    list.add(new Domino(3, 4));
    list.add(new Domino(5, 6));
    list.add(new Domino(1, 4));
    list.add(new Domino(1, 6));

    List<Domino> chain = new ArrayList<>();
    listChains(chain, list);
}
```