# It is possible to generate random numbers sequences from digits in c#?

Tags: c#, numbers, sequence, digits

stackoverflow community,

I want to make c# app, which could generate sequence of the numbers (if previous number last digit equals to second number's first digit). For example, I have data array, which contains: 20, 15, 25, 05, 53, 31 and i need to create all possible sequences.

```
 So, in my case it should be: 
    20 05 53;
    02 25 53 31 15;
    15 53 31;
    25 53 31 15;
    and etc...
```

Digits of the given numbers could be swapped. In one sequence same number can be used only one time (for example 20 and 02, 15 and 51, they can be used only one time in one sequence)
Well, i've tried few code combinations, but none of them worked out ...

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
   string lastDigit = data[i].Substring(1, 1); // setting last digit of the first number
   string generatedSequence = "";
   for (int c = 0; c < data.Length; c++)
   {
     if (lastDigit == data[c].Substring(0, 1)) //if last digit of previous number equals to first digit of next number 
     {
        lastDigit = data[c].Substring(1, 1); // second digit of the number
        generatedSequence = generatedSequence + " " + data[c];
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you need ALL the possible combinations or what exactly is the goal?

Comment: yes, i need ALL the possible commentations

Comment: Uff. That seems to be a complicated thing to do. The topic is called [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation). You can read into that - maybe that helps.

Comment: well, i've found code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48206913/find-all-possible-dominoes-chains-with-recursion-and-backtracking

Comment: could someone can help me to translate it to c# from JAVA?

Comment: I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wished I translated [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48207586/7274172) to C#

Class Domino:
`

```
public class Domino {
    public Domino(int a, int b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }


    public Domino Flipped()
    {
        return new Domino(B, A);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"[{A}/{B}]";
    }

}
```

The Algorithm:

```
    public static void GetList(List<Domino> chain, List<Domino> list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            Domino domino = list[i];

            if (CanAppend(domino, chain))
            {
                chain.Add(domino);
                PrintList(chain);
                list.Remove(domino);
                //You need to create these two lists via the new keyword because 
                //we do not want to keep up the reference to the "old" list. 
                //Otherwise changes in the recoursion would also change the top-level list.
                GetList(new List<Domino>(chain), new List<Domino>(list));
                list.Insert(i, domino);
                chain.Remove(domino);
            }

            var flippedDomino = domino.Flipped();
            if (CanAppend(flippedDomino, chain))
            {
                chain.Add(flippedDomino);
                PrintList(chain);
                list.Remove(domino);
                GetList(new List<Domino>(chain), new List<Domino>(list));
                list.Insert(i, domino);
                chain.Remove(flippedDomino);
            }
        }
    }
```

The two helper methods:

```
    public static bool CanAppend(Domino domino, List<Domino> items)
    {
        return items.Count == 0 || items.Last().B == domino.A;
    }
    private static void PrintList(List<Domino> items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Console.Write(item.ToString());
        }
    }
```

And that's how you use it:

```
List<Domino> list = new List<Domino>();    
// [3/4] [5/6] [1/4] [1/6]   
list.Add(new Domino(3, 4));    
list.Add(new Domino(5, 6));    
list.Add(new Domino(5, 6));    
list.Add(new Domino(1, 4));    
list.Add(new Domino(1, 6));    
List<Domino> chain = new List<Domino>();    
GetList(chain, list);
```

Comment: If you feel like this answered your question please consider marking it as the correct one. (plus I really like reputation)

Comment: Ok. And last question: could you explain me why are you removing domino tile from list, then adding once again? I know you are doing that because of recursion, but im not sure how it works... I know only that methods calls itself...

Comment: You have to re-try every domino with its flipped version. When launching the "new recursion branch" the domino cannot be added to the chain and has to be in the list - otherwise the "flipped Domino" would be added to the list already and could not be added anymore. It would be (so to say) eliminated/used already

Comment: i am not sure, how works these lines:
list.Insert(i, domino);
chain.Remove(domino);

why u are adding domino into list and then removing at specific index?

Comment: Basically I want to recreate the previous setup after launching the new recursive branch. You could also store your two lists in a temporary lists, launch the recursive method with the removed domino and once with the removed flipped domino. That would have the same outcome