# find all possible dominoes chains using recursion

Tags: c#, recursion

I need to find all possibilities for linear chains of dominoes tiles.

Example:

```
Tiles : [3/4] [5/6] [1/4] [1/6]    
Possible chain : [3/4]-[4/1]-[1/6]-[6/5]
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48206913/find-all-possible-dominoes-chains-with-recursion-and-backtracking) I found an example written in Java language. I am newbie, so I am asking for help to translate Java code to c#. I know languages are very similar.

```
private static void listChains(List<Domino> chain, List<Domino> list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
    {
        Domino dom = list[i];
        if (canAppend(dom, chain))
        {
            chain.Add(dom);
            Console.WriteLine(chain);
            Domino saved = list.RemoveAt(i);
            listChains(chain, list);
            list.Add(new Domino(i, saved));
            chain.Remove(chain.Count() - 1);
        }
        dom = dom.flipped();
        if (canAppend(dom, chain))
        {
            chain.Add(dom);
            Console.WriteLine(chain);
            Domino saved = list.RemoveAt(i);
            listChains(chain, list);
            list.Add(new Domino(i, saved));
            chain.RemoveAt(chain.Count() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'ConsoleApp2.Domino' to 'int'       23  Active
>   Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'ConsoleApp2.Domino'       21  Active
>   Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'ConsoleApp2.Domino'       24  Active
>   Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'ConsoleApp2.Domino'       31  Active
>   Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'ConsoleApp2.Domino' to 'int'       33  Active
>   Error   CS1061  'int' does not contain a definition for 'b' and no accessible extension method 'b' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)        42  Active

```
Domino saved = list.RemoveAt(i); list.Add(new Domino(i, saved));
chain.Remove(chain.Count() - 1); Domino saved = list.RemoveAt(i);
list.Add(new Domino(i, saved));
```

And I am not sure what this method does:(and how to translate to c#)

```
private static boolean canAppend(Domino dom, List<Domino> to) {
    return to.isEmpty() || to.get(to.size()-1).b == dom.a;
}
```

Comment: I know you say you're a newbie, but have you at least tried?  Even if you can't get it to work it will give us something to debug and give you pointers on.

Comment: I would recommend at least trying to solve the problem first or clarifying your definition of "linear chains" to make the problem more clear rather than simply just linking another question.

Comment: Doug F, yes, i've tried, but got many errors in visual studio

Comment: Can you specify what errors you're getting, and on which lines?

Comment: Domino saved = list.RemoveAt(i);
list.Add(new Domino(i, saved));
chain.Remove(chain.Count() - 1);
Domino saved = list.RemoveAt(i);
list.Add(new Domino(i, saved));

Comment: It  appears for CS1503 you are passing a `Domino` to a method where it expects an `int`, and in CS0029 you are trying to assign a `Domino` to the result of a method that returns `void` (`RemoveAt`).

Comment: That method checks to see if the list is empty and returns `true` if it is. If it's not empty, it compares the `b` property of the last domino in the list with the `a` property of the `dom` argument, and returns `true` if they match. Otherwise it returns `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a shot at a conversion of the code you posted:

```
public class Domino
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }

    public Domino(int a, int b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }

    public Domino Flipped()
    {
        return new Domino(B, A);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"[{A}/{B}]";
    }
}   

public class Program
{
    private static void ListChains(List<Domino> chain, List<Domino> list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
        {
            Domino dom = list[i];

            if (CanAppend(dom, chain))
            {
                chain.Add(dom);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-", chain));
                Domino saved = list[i];
                list.RemoveAt(i);
                ListChains(chain, list);
                list.Insert(i, saved);
                chain.RemoveAt(chain.Count - 1);
            }

            dom = dom.Flipped();

            if (CanAppend(dom, chain))
            {
                chain.Add(dom);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-", chain));
                Domino saved = list[i];
                list.RemoveAt(i);
                ListChains(chain, list);
                list.Insert(i, saved);
                chain.RemoveAt(chain.Count - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool CanAppend(Domino domino, List<Domino> chain)
    {
        return chain == null || chain.Count == 0 || chain.Last().B == domino?.A;
    }

    private static void Main()
    {
        var dominos = new List<Domino>
        {
            new Domino(3, 4),
            new Domino(5, 6),
            new Domino(1, 4),
            new Domino(1, 6)
        };

        ListChains(new List<Domino>(), dominos);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image: ![![enter image description here]

Comment: i am not sure, how works these lines:
list.Insert(i, domino);
chain.Remove(domino);

why u are adding domino into list and then removing at specific index?

Comment: The method is recursive, so we modify the list and chain, make the recursive call, then put it back together again for the next iteration. During each recursive call, the list gets shorter and the chain gets longer. Then as the recursive calls unwind, the chain goes back to nothing and the list is restored so we can test the next domino.

Comment: We pick a domino in the `for` loop, if it can be appended to the chain then we remove it from the list, add it to the chain, and do a recursive call to this same method (with the modified chain and list). Then after the recursive call is done, we add the item back to the list and remove it from the chain so we can test the flipped version, then do it all again with the flipped version, and then put things back together for the next loop iteration.